# Regex and Redirection Plugin

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect, plugins

My blog was originally set up as follows: `/blog/`

For some time, it has been as follows: `/posts-2/`

I need to know an expression to direct from `/blog/` to `/posts-2/`

Here's an example of (many) 404s I'm getting: `mysite.com/blog/post-name/`

Also, I need to be able to use it in conjunction with the date/permalink solution,
Source:

```
/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*) Target: /$4
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/posts-2$1 [R=301,L]
```

(I don't get the last part of your question about date/permalink)